# How to open .RDS file into replit

Tags: r, replit

So I am currently working on a school project with a group where we have to create a program in R using variables in a rds file. Normally we open that file in R Studio but since we are in a group I wanted to see if that file could be opened in replit where we all could contribute to the code rather than all of us individually doing it ourselves. When I tried to open it in the shell in Replit the variables came up as non-readable and showed weird characters and null, not sure if there is a way to go around this or a proper way of doing it.

the .rds file contains over 150 variables that are needed to base our code around to

I opened the file in replit and the file came as un-readable with null values, not sure what other ways can be done other than uploading it

Comment: Welcome to SO. As is stands, it is not possible to answer your question with the information you have provided. Please check out [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2530121) for how to ask a good homework question on SO. This will increase the likelihood of getting an answer. Thanks